# How to change name of Zotero reference label

Tags: overleaf, back-referencing, zotero

I've linked up my Zotero and Overleaf accounts and am working on references for a document. Two of the references are being given the exact same label but I can't edit the bib file within Overleaf it seems. How do I edit one of the labels to something different?

Comment: The Zotero importer on Overleaf just takes the output of the Zotero exporter API; the imported file cannot be edited manually nor changed by Overleaf's importer. You may want to export the .bib file from Zotero Desktop directly, where you have better control over export options and _then_ upload the .bib file to your Overleaf project.

Comment: @LianTzeLim - Ok, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add a line with

```
Citation Key: <something>
```

in the `extra` field, that will be used as the citation key by Zotero, and consequently by Overleaf when you connect it to Zotero. You can automate this using the [Better BibTeX](https://retorque.re/zotero-better-bibtex/) Zotero plugin (full disclosure: I am the author of this plugin), but all it does for this particular use-case is automate putting the key in the `extra` field. To get the key there, you need to select your items and choose "Pin Key" from the right-click menu.